# Encryption android file

Tags: java, android, sqlite, encryption, cryptography

I would like to store data in a sqlite dabatase on an android app.

If someone finds the phone, it will be super easy for him to retrieve this database and explore it so I would like to encrypt it.

I've found that https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/ is the best option but to encrypt it, we need a key (SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(“thisismysecret”)

It the key is stored in the code of the android app, it stills unsafe right ? (I think it is not super difficult to reverse engineer an apk)

So I would like to ask the user to enter a secret word which will be used to encrypt the data.
I also don't have to bother the user asking him the password on each action so I tought about asking him it at every launch of the app. It means that I have to store it in a variable.

So my question is : is there any way for a hacker who may stole the phone to view "live data" such as stored variable in a running android app. I mean can he dump the live state of an android app and parse object in real time (like the Eclipse step by step debugger for instance)

Comment: `it will be super easy for him to retrieve this database and explore it`. possible, yes. super easy, i wouldn't go that far. you need to root the device to begin with.

Comment: I agree, not super easy but possible you're right

Answer (score 0):

You should hash (MD5) the password, store the hashed version, and call the database using the hashed key. Then when the password is entered, the hashed version should be compared to the stored value.

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
digest.update(inputPassword.getBytes());
byte[] hashedPassword = digest.digest();
```

Comment: Actually I don't really care if the user types the right or the wrong password, if the wrong password is typed, the decryption won't work and I'm fine with that

Comment: MD5 must not be used as a password hash or a key derivation function. It's broken.

Comment: Its better to use SHA-1 or SHA-256. MD5 is completely broken

Comment: Thanks but my question was not about how to store the password